# How to get the device id of Raspberry Pi while sending data to IBM Bluemix as a gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, raspberry-pi3, watson-iot

I am sending data from Sense HAT (device) through a Raspberry Pi (gateway) to my Bluemix application. My Pi is also sending CPU temperature of Raspberry Pi to Bluemix. I have one IBM IoT node receiving both of the data. I am not able to differentiate the Sense HAT data from Raspberry Pi data. Here is the function node code:

```
var v;
if(msg.deviceId==="raspberryID")
{
    v= "From Raspberry Pi";
}
  else if (msg.deviceId=="senseHatid")
{
  v= "From Sense Hat";
}
return {payload:v}
```

Return value is always "From Sense Hat," but I am able to receive both the data in debug. I get the same result if I use `msg.deviceType` in the if else statement.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. I am able to differentiate the Sense Hat from Raspberry Pi. Double check the device Ids and see.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are publishing all the data from the Raspberry Pi and the SenseHAT using the senseHatid.

Are you using Node-RED to publish the readings from the Raspberry Pi?  If so ensure, that you are setting the msg.deviceType and msg.deviceId values for the outbound Watson IoT node to the Raspberry Pi gateway for the CPU temperature and the SenseHit device for the senseHat data.